# Weird Picturebox Behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I have this program that i have 10 pictureboxes if the textbox of form1 is the same as the text in the textbox of form3 it will show the picture of a check mark otherwise it will show the picture of a crossmark..But when I typed in the answers when it shows the result it only shows one picturebox and one picturebox and always shows a checkmark which is not doing the purpose of the program and the other nine pictureboxes were missing.. (I already checked the pictureboxes and it the enabled and visible properties were all set to TRUE) Thanks in advance guys I hope you can help me with this problem.

```
Imports System.Convert
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
Imports System.Drawing.Image

Public Class Form4
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Public frm1 As Form1
Private frm2 As Form2
Public frm3 As Form3
Private frm4 As Form4
Private frm5 As Form5
Private Form5 As Form5


Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lbl3 As Integer
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3)

    Me.Visible = False


End Sub
Public Sub New1(ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New5(ByVal callerInstance As Form2)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm2 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New4(ByVal callerInstance As Form3)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm3 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New3(ByVal callerInstance As Form4)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm4 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New5(ByVal callerInstance As Form5)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm5 = callerInstance
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm1 As Form1 = Form1
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = Form2
    Dim frm3 As Form3 = Form3
    Dim frm5 As Form5 = Form5


    If frm5 Is Nothing Then
        frm5 = New Form5(Me)
        AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form5HasBeenClosed



        frm5.Label21.Text = frm1.TextBox1.Text
        frm5.Label21.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label22.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text
        frm5.Label22.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label23.Text = frm1.TextBox3.Text
        frm5.Label23.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label24.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text
        frm5.Label24.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label25.Text = frm1.TextBox5.Text
        frm5.Label25.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label26.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text
        frm5.Label26.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label27.Text = frm1.TextBox7.Text
        frm5.Label27.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm2.Label28.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text
        frm2.Label28.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label29.Text = frm1.TextBox9.Text
        frm5.Label29.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label30.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text
        frm5.Label30.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label31.Text = frm1.TextBox11.Text
        frm5.Label31.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label32.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text
        frm5.Label32.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label33.Text = frm1.TextBox13.Text
        frm5.Label33.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label34.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text
        frm5.Label34.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label35.Text = frm1.TextBox15.Text
        frm5.Label35.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label36.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text
        frm5.Label36.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label37.Text = frm1.TextBox17.Text
        frm5.Label37.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label38.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text
        frm5.Label38.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label39.Text = frm1.TextBox19.Text
        frm5.Label39.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label40.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text
        frm5.Label40.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
    If frm5 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm5.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form  
        Me.Hide()
    End If

    If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox2.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox1.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

        frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")

    Else
        frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")


        If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox4.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox2.Text.Trim(), True)) Then
            frm5.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")

        Else

            frm5.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

            If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox6.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox3.Text.Trim(), True)) Then
                frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
            Else

                frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox8.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox4.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

                    frm5.PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                Else
                    frm5.PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                    If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox10.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox5.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

                        frm5.PictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                    Else
                        frm5.PictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                        If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox12.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox6.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

                            frm5.PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                        Else
                            frm5.PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                            If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox14.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox7.Text.Trim(), True)) Then
                                frm5.PictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                            Else
                                frm5.PictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                                If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox16.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox8.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

                                    frm5.PictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                                Else
                                    frm5.PictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                                    If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox18.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox9.Text.Trim(), True)) Then
                                        frm5.PictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                                    Else
                                        frm5.PictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")

                                        If CBool(String.Compare(frm1.TextBox20.Text.Trim(), frm3.TextBox10.Text.Trim(), True)) Then

                                            frm5.PictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\checkmark.jpg")
                                        Else

                                            frm5.PictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\vbproject\vbp\crossmark.jpg")




                                            frm5.Show()
                                            Me.Hide()
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If frm5 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm5.Visible = False

        frm5.Show() 'Show Second Form  

        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form5HasBeenClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues here that needs to be addressed:
1. You have pasted far to much code. All  you needed was to paste the If statements (Because that is where you are having problem, and that is where the problem is).
2. And this is regarding your problem:

String.Compare will give you the result 0 if two strings match. 0 (which is also known as false if you convert it to Boolean). So when two strings match you correctly display a Cross. Compare will also tell you which String is bigger than the other. 1 if the first one is bigger, -1 if it isn't (Sidetrack not important here). I suggest you do the following instead:

```
 If frm1.TextBox2.Text.ToUpper().Equals(frm3.TextBox1.Text.ToUpper()) Then
```

In this case it is pretty obvious what happends. If string 1 is equal to string two then the result is True. No CBool required.

Your ifstatements are messed up. Question 2-oo will only be addressed if the first statement is false. I will show you what I mean.

```
   If statement = true Then
     Display checkmark
   Else
     Display cross
     'Now you do the next one inside the else statement
     If statement2 = True Then 
        'Display checkmark
     Else 
        Display cross
        'And then you continue the nesting
     End If
   End If
```

What you need to do is this:

```
If statement = true Then
'Display check
Else
'Display cross
End If 'Notice how I close the ifstatement before I go to the next one.

If statement2 = true Then
'Display check
Else
'Display cross
End If

etc...
```

I hope you get this, otherwise let me know and I'll try to simplify it further.